# WordPress Remove autoP on Widget only

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, siteorigin

all solutions I found here werte global (remove filter auto) or didn't work, so I hope you guys have other solutions too ;)

I am writing a plugin with new widgets for the siteorigin page builder. I guess this is just a sideinfo, I don't think it is siteorigin problem.

Whenever I output content from the tinymce / WYSIWYG-Editor, it wraps p-tags around the content. I don't want this. Is there a chance to prevent the auto-p from the widget, but not global, as I want it to work on pages, posts and other widgets.

I am thinking of something like

I tried to replace

```
$mytext = preg_replace('#^<\/p>|<p>$#', '', $text);
```

and I tried to prevent the filter

```
echo remove_filter( $text, 'wpautop' );
```

Both didn't work for me. So YOU could be my hero now...
thank you guys.

Comment: I don't think that you can remove them. I believe that the widget is using `wpautop` or `apply_filters(''the_content', $content)`. You should remove this functions, or you should add `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` above you code and `add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` after the content is printed.

Comment: HI @StanimirStoyanov - thx for your quick reply! I have to echo the content from the siteorigin like: echo $instance['opt_section']['quote']; not with "the content" or "get_the_content". So I don't know how to pass it through the filter. Could you help me with this? I am sorry, maybe I am just thinking to complex now.

Comment: Can you add `remove_filter('the_content','wpautop')` before `echo $instance['opt_section']['quote'];`

Comment: I have added the code as follows, but still i get these p-tags :( <?php 

    remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');
    echo $instance['opt_section']['quote'];

   ?>

Comment: Well I think that the variable contains these p tags. You can try with this code then `preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '', $instance['opt_section']['quote']);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your efford @StanimirStoyanov - but still, no change. I'll open a support ticket and post the answer over here afterwards. all the best